# Using JQuery with Dart for Input autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart

I've been having trouble using JQuery with Dart to allow an input field to suggest text from a pre-selected list.

I am getting a NoSuchMethod error with the following code:

```
js.scoped(() {
    js.context.jQuery("#input").autocomplete({source: ['hi', 'hello', 'bye']});
});
```

(Just a note, I tried to avoid JQuery for this, but the only Dart auto suggest library I found -- autocomplete-ui -- threw me errors every time I tried to put the component in my template.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the no such method error happening? here `.jQuery("#input")`? or was it here: `.autocomplete(`

Comment: @KevinB The `jQuery()` method.

Comment: if jQuery is not defined on js.context, then that's your problem. either jQuery isn't properly defined, or you're referencing it incorrectly. I'm not familiar enough with dart to know how you should be referencing jQuery within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```dart
js.context.jQuery("#input")
  .autocomplete(js.map({'source': ['hi', 'hello', 'bye']}));
```

Basically you have to convert the Dart map with `js.map`.

You can also get rid of `js.scoped` that is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm still getting the same error: Breaking on exception: `NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'jQuery'`

Comment: It's easier with the error :) You have to either use `js.context.$("#input")....` or add the following javascript to your page : `<script>$.noConflict()</script>` (see [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I realized I did not import jquery.js and jquery-ui.js into my directory (I just assumed it came with the js library). It works whether it's `js.context.jQuery` or `js.context.$` but the `js.map()` call was necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you want an update ? Using js package this code is still valid.